# Do you know how to properly move this code from the view to the controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code below in a view to show a summary of a registration like:

```
Registration type        Quantity            Price           Subtotal
general                     1                0.00             0.00
plus                        2                2.00             4.00
```

Code in the view to show the summary:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Registration Type</span>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <span >Price</span>
        <span>Subtotal</span>
    </li>

    <?php
    $total = 0;
    $type_counts = [];
    foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
        $name = $p->registration_type->name;
        if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
            $type_counts[$name] = 0;
        }
        $type_counts[$name]++;
    }
    ?>
    @foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
        @php ($name = $participant->registration_type->name)
        @php ($total +=$participant->registration_type->price * $type_counts[$name])
        <li>
            <span>{{$name}}</span>
            <span>{{$type_counts[$name]}}</span>
            <span>{{ number_format($participant->registration_type->price, 2)}}$</span>
            <span>{{ number_format($participant->registration_type->price * $type_counts[$name], 2)}}$</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>{{ number_format($total, 2)}}€</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It is working fine, but I want to pass the php code above that is in the view to the controller showSummary() method and then return to the view the necessary data to show the summary, but I'm not having success in achieving this.

Do you know how this can be properly achieved?

I have in the controller the `showSummary()` method that returns the "registrationTypeDetails" to the above view.

```
public function showSummary($id, $slug, $regID)
    {
        $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with(['participants.registration_type',
            'participants' => function ($query) use ($regID) {
                $query->select('id', 'registration_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $regID);
            }
        ])->find($regID);

        return view('conferences.showSummary', compact('registrationTypeDetails', 'id', 'slug'));
    }
```

What I did to achieve this was put in the controller the part to count the quantity of each registration type like:

```
public function payment($id, $slug, $regID)
    {
        $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with(['participants.registration_type',
            'participants' => function ($query) use ($regID) {
                $query->select('id', 'registration_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $regID);
            }
        ])->find($regID);

        $type_counts = [];
        foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
            $name = $p->registration_type->name;
            if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
                $type_counts[$name] = 0;
            }
            $type_counts[$name]++;
        }

        $registrationTypes = [];

        return view('conferences.payment', compact( 'type_counts', 'registrationTypeDetails', 'id', 'slug'));
    }
```

And in the view just:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Registration Type</span>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <span>Price</span>
        <span>Subtotal</span>
    </li>
    <?php
    $total = 0;
    ?>
    @foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
        @php ($name = $participant->registration_type->name)
        @php ($total +=$participant->registration_type->price * $type_counts[$name])
        <li>
            <span>{{$name}}</span>
            <span>{{$type_counts[$name]}}</span>
            <span>{{ number_format($participant->registration_type->price, 2)}}
                €</span>
            <span>{{ number_format($participant->registration_type->price * $type_counts[$name], 2)}}
                €</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>{{ number_format($total, 2)}}€</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But, I don't know if this is ok, if there is more code that should go to the controller. Because I need to store in the session the total value of the registration ( `$total`) but the total value ($total) is in the view not in the controller which dont seems correct.

Comment: So what have you tried? A lot of that code belongs in the view. Pull out the logic that you think belongs in the controller and then post your specific question when you can't get that to work.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with more details and what I have but I dont know if its a correct approach and also how the total value should be stored in the session, because the total value is in the view and maybe is better to store the $total value in session in the controller.

Comment: Have you thought of maybe using the collection's `map` method to iterate through your results and update each record with those calculations you are performing on your view? That way you can have each of the computational fields populated within the controller and just spit out each record with that info readily available. And my assumption is that your model returns a collection object obviously.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example of that collection´s map approach?

Comment: $registrationTypeDetails returns: Registration {#259 ▼
    ... #relations: array:1 [▼  "participants" => Collection {#263 ▼#items: array:2 [▼
      0 => Participant {#270 ▼ ...#relations: array:1 [▼ "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#276 ▼    ....
         #attributes: array:12 [▼"id" => 2 "name" => "free" "price" => 0"conference_id" => 2] ... }]... }1 => Participant {#272 ▼...#relations: array:1 [▼"registration_type" => RegistrationType {#278 ▼... #attributes: array:12 [▼"id" => 3"name" => "paid""price" => 1 "conference_id," => 2 ] ...}]} ]} ] ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is neither.

A controller is for passing data from one place to another, and a view is for displaying data. A good rule is that if you’re writing PHP and creating arrays in a Blade template, you’re doing too much (which it sounds like you’re aware of).

Make yourself a folder called `repositories` in your app, and create a `RegistrationRepository` or something similar. Build your table as a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) – or get it from Eloquent in a more efficient way. Then use a [Collection `map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map) to create your total. Pass that data into the view and then simply loop through it and display it.

Keep your models and controllers lightweight, create new classes to keep complex logic in. There’s also an argument that this could be done as a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers), but I think as you’re creating extra information and reading from a few places, creating a repository for it is the cleanest.

*However* this is an opinion, not an answer. There isn’t a definitive answer sadly, as MVC is what you want it to be really. Rails likes heavy models, CodeIgniter liked heavy Controllers. *Personally* I believe Laravel is about having light controllers and light models – but that’s up to you to decide if you agree.

Comment: I concur with the Collection suggestion and perhaps creating a repository for his model is the best way to go since it will not do any harm anyways in my opinion.